# PHP string whitespace formatting

Tags: php

```
$str = "Test Artist Test - Test Title Test";  
$trackinfo = preg_split('/-/', $str);

exec('metamp3 --title '.$trackinfo[1].' --artist '.$trackinfo[0].' track.mp3');
```

This is a cut of the code I am using, basically I'm obviously doing something wrong (I'm quite new to PHP and don't really understand some of the conventions used. When I run this line, from what I can see it would only put Test and Test for the title and artist (like it is only taking the first word from the string) but if I was to do something like

```
print_r $trackinfo;
print $trackinfo[1];
print $trackinfo[0];
```

I can clearly see that the split string is formatted correctly, I was wondering if someone could explain what exactly is going on here and how I would go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a PHP problem. You're passing following string to exec:

```
metamp3 --title Test Title Test --artist Test Artist Test track.mp3
```

But *metamp3* program will take only first word for each parameter. The command should look like `metamp3 --title "Test Title Test" ...` (parameter value in quotes).

There is function in PHP to solve this problem: [`escapeshellarg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). Here is how your code can look like:

```
exec(
    'metamp3 --title '.escapeshellarg($trackinfo[1]).
    ' --artist '.escapeshellarg($trackinfo[0]).' track.mp3'
);
```

Comment: You're awesome sir, I thought (hoped) there would be a way to tackle this but I wasn't aware of a solution. Thank you, so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add quotes:

```
exec('metamp3 --title "'.$trackinfo[1].'" --artist "'.$trackinfo[0].'" track.mp3');
```

Comment: This will fail if there are `"` symbols in song name.

Comment: @Ivan Nevostruev, yeah, you are correct! Your decision is better.